# is there PowerBuilder client? to get the multiple instances from the server?

Tags: powerbuilder

is there PowerBuilder client? to get the multiple instances from the server?
or can able to share the Software?

If it is possible, please kindly tell me the way to get that instances

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I follow your question entirely but I'll try.

PowerBuilder is a standalone IDE that is used to build compiled applications (written in Powerscript).  As far as the IDE, each developer must have their own license to use PowerBuilder (I believe they do allow a developer to have a copy on their work computer and on a laptop for travel with a single license).

There is no runtime license required on the applications you build, so if you purchase PowerBuilder, you can freely distribute the PB runtime with any applications you distribute so that anyone can run them on their computer.